# How to check programmatically for the existence of a docker image before calling create_namespaced_pod() of kubernetes

Tags: python, python-3.x, docker, kubernetes

I am using `create_namespaced_pod()` of the `kubernetes-client` package to dynamically create kubernetes pods from docker images that are in an images registry.

How do I check if the Docker image exists in the registry before calling `create_namespaced_pod()`? I want to avoid creating the pod and then having to deal with error messages.

Answer (score 1):

you may use [`docker registry ls`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/registry_ls/) to list the contents of your registry and parse for your image specifically. if `ls` isn't working for you, you can try a simple HTTP call to the image's URL in the registry, and check the response code.